# Assign $.ajax to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm not getting any output the id_function.php works perfectly fine can anyone please help me?

JavaScript

```
 function get_details()
    {
        var oriz = document.getElementById("from").value;
        var dizz = document.getElementById("to").value;

        var id_orig_diz = $.ajax({
            type: "POST", 
            url: 'id_function.php?orig='+oriz+'&des_id='+dizz,
            dataType: "text", 
            async: false
                        }).responseText;
        alert(id_orig_diz); 

    }
```

This is my PHP but I'm not getting any id

```
            <?php
            $name_1 = $_GET['orig'];
            $name_2 = $_GET['des_id'];
            try {
                $dbuser = "kim";
                $dbpass = "kim";
                $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=destination', $dbuser, $dbpass);
                $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);    
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT pl_id FROM view_places WHERE name = :name LIMIT 1");

                $stmt->bindParam(':name',$name_1); 
                $stmt->execute();
                $result_1 = $stmt -> fetch();
                $res1 = $result_1["pl_id"];  

                $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name_2); 
                $stmt->execute(); 
                $result_2 = $stmt -> fetch(); 
                    $res2 = $result_2["pl_id"];  
                    echo   'origin_number:'.$res1. ', '.'destination_id:'.$res2;
                }   catch(PDOException $e) {
                        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
                }

            ?>
```

Comment: You have to wait for the AJAX call to finish.

Comment: you can use the `.done(function(data) {....})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will not work because AJAX calls are asynchronous which means that they don't immediately return a value after you execute them. It has to go out to the server, let the serverside code run and then provide a value back. Think of it as similar in many ways to kicking off a thread in another language; you have to wait for the thread to yield control back to your application.

```
var id_orig_diz = $.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    url: 'id_function.php?orig='+oriz+'&des_id='+dizz,
    dataType: "text", 
    async: false
}).responseText;
```

What you need to do is set a result handler like this:

```
var id_orig_diz;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    url: 'id_function.php?orig='+oriz+'&des_id='+dizz,
    dataType: "text", 
    async: false,
    success: function(data){
        id_orig_diz = data; //or something similar
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

try instead this because when you make the alert the ajax call can't be finish yet. With the suucess function you are secure that the ajax call is finished, you have to echo something into your php file if you want a response:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST", 
   url: 'id_function.php',
   dataType: "text", 
   data: { 'orig': oriz, 'des_id' : dizz },
   async: false,
   success: function(data){
      alert(data);
   }
})
```

Into your php file you can take values in this mode:

```
<?php
$orig = $_POST['orig'];
$des_id = $_POST['des_id'];
?>
```

Comment: let me know if this is what you want @jake

Comment: I agree this is the better way to write it, but consider the call is executing synchronously since `async: false` was specified. That said, asynchronous calls should always be used, following the pattern from this answer.

Comment: Return some error in your console? Have you echo something into your php file?

Comment: i had echo in my php file.. i just used alert to test if my code works

Comment: you can see into your console into the network tab the call ajax to your php file if return something or not

Comment: when i used "http://localhost/map/id_function.php?orig=a_value&des_id=value" im getting an id

Comment: I have update my answer to pass right the value, into your php file you can take the value orgi and des_id like this: $_POST['orig'] for example try @jake

Comment: @Alessandro Minoccheri instead of $_GET i used $_POST ?

Comment: im getting an echo output but no id-> origin_number:, destination_id:

Answer (score 2):

The recommended method is to use a `success` function to receive the data and assign your ID. From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> **success**
>
> Type: Function( PlainObject data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )

You should use the `data` parameter to get your ID.

---

The code is the same as in Alessandro's answer:

```
success: function(data){
    alert(data);
}
```

Comment: can you pls post the entire sample script using above iv really appreciate and thanks alot